# Derivative of $f(x)= x^2\cos{1\over x},x\neq 0 ,\\=0,x=0 $

Tags: calculus, limits

On diffrentiating we get
$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(x)=2x\cos\frac1x -\sin\frac1x$

This shows that dervative as $ x\to 0 , $ is not defined while if we use first principle 
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^2\sin\frac1h}{h}=0$$
Why is there a contradiction.Is diffrentiation not applicable on fluctuating 
functions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f'(0)$ exists. $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ does not exist. Where's the contradiction in that?

Comment: The function is differentiable, as you showed, but the derivative is not continuous at $x=0$. So?

Comment: A continuous function does not necessarily have to be differentiable. The absolute value function is a good example of this.

Comment: You are perhaps thinking as to why the formula for the derivative of $f(x) $ is not valid when $x=0$. Note that the existence of derivative at a set of points does not in anyway guarantee the existence of a simple formula for the derivative which holds for all of these points.

Comment: Is it not true that derivative of $f(x)$ is basically the value of the $[f(x+h)-f(x)]/h$ as h tends to zero. Both should be giving the same value for x.In the above case one of the expression says that derivative does not exist while other gives 0

Answer (score 1):

Derivative is defined via the equation $$f'(a) =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\tag{1}$$ and using the above definition it is easy to prove the rules of differentiation (sum, product, quotient, chain rule etc) and also calculate derivatives of elementary functions in a straightforward manner. To make things easier one keeps a ready made table for derivatives of basic functions and then uses the rules of differentiation to compute the derivatives of elementary functions.

So in practice we don't evaluate the derivatives of elementary functions by directly applying the definition $(1)$ but rather use tables and rules for differentiation. This approach which sometimes goes by the name *mechanical differentiation* (especially when the proof for the rules and the table of derivatives is not provided) is a very fast technique for the evaluation of derivatives. And it can be used to find the derivatives of elementary functions *except for certain exceptional points in their domain*. Thus the formula $(\sqrt{x}) '=1/2\sqrt{x}$ does not work for $x=0$. But even in such cases the formula does indicate correctly that the derivative becomes infinite at $0$ (better to say that the tangent is parallel to $y$ axis). This is always the case with elementary functions and mechanical differentiation is sufficient to find the derivative whether finite or infinite.

The process of mechanical differentiation does not apply for functions which are non-elementary precisely because we don't have a proper classification of such functions and we don't have corresponding table of derivatives.

In your case the function $\phi(x) =x^{2}\cos(1/x)$ is elementary and mechanical differentiation gives us the formula $$\phi'(x) = 2x\cos(1/x)+\sin(1/x)$$ and this works for all points in domain of $\phi$ and things work exactly as expected. When you specifically choose to enlarge the domain of $\phi$ by making it continuous at $0$ then we get the function of the question $$f(x) =x^{2}\cos(1/x),f(0)=0$$ which is non-elementary and one can not use the mechanical differentiation to get its derivative at the point $0$. And then we have to get back to the definition $(1)$ to find the derivative.

The above description can be concisely written as follows:

> If $f$ is an elementary function then $f$ is continuous on its domain and differentiatiable on its domain except for some specific points and further the derivative $f'$ is an elementary function so it is also continuous on its domain. These properties do not hold if $f$ is non-elementary and we should not expect in general that the derivative $f'$ is continuous on its domain.

Comment: In your example of $f(x) = √x$ the derivative does not exist at x=0.It can be shown by both methods the first derivative and by putting $x=0$ in $f'(x)$ that is both equations do not contradict themselves .At first glance one would say that they will never contradict as the second method is actually a direct result of the first principle.  So why the function that I gave is giving a contradiction.                    Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @varangrai: I am saying that mechanical differentiation is guaranteed only to work for elementary functions. I have also said that for elementary functions the mechanical differentiation gives expected results at the exceptional points also. So this works for $\sqrt{x} $ at $0$ also without any problem. In fact you can see that it gives expected results for $|x|=\sqrt{x^{2}}$ also. Your function in question is non-elementary so the method of mechanical differentiation does not work at $0$.

Comment: @varangrai: Thus there is no contradiction in both methods (as expected). Your confusion arises because you are trying to treat your function $f$ as an elementary function. This is not true.

Answer (score 0):

To answer whether a function is differentiable at value $x$, we just have to evaluate the $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

When $x\neq 0$, you can use product rule to compute that and in fact you did. Let me denote the expression by $f_1(x)$.

You can't use product rule when $x=0$ as the function is not a product of two differentiable functions. Also, we do not have any result to claim that $f'(0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f_1(x)$ if it exists.

When $x=0$, you use the definition and you obtain that the derivative is equal to $0$.

You have proven that the derivative exists everywhere.

There is no reason why $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f_1(x) = f'(0).$$ That claim would imply that the derivative is continuous, of which you have argued that it is not true.

Main take away for the question can be derivative of a function need not be continuous.